# Spring cloud stream test a method that sends a message through custom channel at the end

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-test

I have created a custom channel in Spring cloud stream with custom inputs and outputs. Let's suppose this is the created channel:

```
public interface Channel {

  String FOO = "foo-request";
  String BAR = "bar-response";

  @Input(FOO)
  SubscribableChannel fooRequest();

  @Output(BAR)
  MessageChannel barResponse();

}
```

Something.java:

```
public class Something{

  @Autowired
  private Channel channel;

  public void doSomething(..){
    // Do some steps
    channel.barRequest().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(outputMessage).build())
  }

}
```

As it can be seen I am injecting the custom channel in the `Something` class to send the message at the end of a method.

When I would like to test this method, I am having some issues with the injection done in the `Something` class. I cannot inject the `Something` class because it's not a component. But this class injects a `Channel` object as it can be seen. So here is what I have done to pass the limitation of injecting an internal property for this class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyChannel.class})

public class SomethingTest{

  @Autowired
  private Channel myChannel;

  @Test
  public void TestDoSomething(){
  // cannot inject it as it does not have any qualified bean
  Something something = new Something();
  ReflectionTestUtils.setField(something, "channel", channel);
  }

  @EnableBinding(Channel.class)
  public static class MyChannel {

  }
}
```

Without the `ReflectionTestUtls` line, I am getting a `NullPointerException` on `channel.barRequest().send()` in the `doSomething` method. With having this line to pass the injected object, I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.bar-response'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
```

First of all, I am not sure if what I am doing is the best way of dealing with my custom channel and testing the corresponding method, so please let me know if there is a better way. Second, why am I getting this exception and how I can address it?

P.S: I have already set the required configurations in my `application.yml` file for the test related to the binders and channels in a similar way that I have been doing with running the application in a normal way. This approach has been working so far with other properties.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing noticing is you try to send to your *Input* Channel which typically recevies the messages.

Try changing it to `channel.barResponse().send(...)`

---

Other then that i am facing the same issue, but with a more complicated use-case. We have already definied our rabbit queues.